# Apache URL Rewrite /client/client to /client

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy

I am attempting to change the URL of my site, to make it more user friendly.

Currently users must navigate to `www.domain.com/client/client/`. I wish to display this as just `www.domain.com/client`. However, I still require the file path `/client/client` to exist (IE: there are files in /client/client that use `../folder`, and I need these to still work)

Does anyone know if RewriteRule can accomplish this, or how else to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve the URL www.domain.com/client/foo.html then any links inside that page that refer ../folder/bar will (by the browser) be converted to www.domain.com/folder/bar . So there's no point in the file path client/client existing.